# Validation of Akamai caching

Tags: akamai

We have cached html and png pages in Akamai by changing the waa config. But unable to validate it through fiddler, live http headers or through curl commands. Below are the screenshots. Please help if I missed any headers

[Fiddler:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8rtz.png)
[live http header](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtZ4Z.png)
Curl command :

$ curl -H "Pragma: akamai-x-cache-on, akamai-x-cache-remote-on, akamai-x-check-cacheable, akamai-x-get-cache-key, akamai-x-get-extracted-values, akamai-x-get-nonces, akamai-x-get-ssl-client-session-id, akamai-x-get-true-cache-key, akamai-x-serial-no" -IXGET "url"

Response :
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 20 Oct 2016 19:15:53 GMT
Content-Length: 19836
Content-Type: image/png
X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY

Answer (score 1):

Well in Akamai WAF(Web Application Firewall) there are few WAF rules that prevent  display of pragma headers to users. You need to create an exception for those WAF rules and add only trusted IP's to it. Then you will be able to see the information that you are looking for. Thanks, Vinod

Answer (score 1):

I would double check that you are definitely sending that Pragma header with the request and that it is also properly formed. I've seen a lot of problems with people trying to set this up and not getting it right.

Also it's worth reviewing your Akamai configuration because it is also possible to switch this off - some clients prefer to do this for security reasons.